# Using WIX to create a installer that installs to a predefined location

Tags: wix, wix3.5

I'm trying to create a (hopefully) simple installer using WIX, however it seems I'm at my wits end. I cannot for the life of me figure out how to specify a predefined path to install my files. What the installer need to do is this:

1. Install 4 fonts
2. Install (copy) a binary file and a .ini file to a predefined path ("C:\dvimport")
3. Create shortcut to previous binary on the desktop
4. Run a binary installer provided along-side (hopefully bundled inside) the installer.

Also, on a side note; the user **should not** be able to change the predefined path, cause the application will not run if not installed on the correct path.

Currently what I have is this (which is mostly predefined):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
  <Product Id="660d9ab6-dbd9-4440-b56b-8f1c29d9ab86" Name="FDVweb hjelpefiler" Language="1033" Version="1.0.0.0" Manufacturer="CuroTech" UpgradeCode="4283b7c8-0057-4dcc-bfc5-7c06a12cba90">
    <Package InstallerVersion="200" Compressed="yes" Keywords="Installer" Description="FDVweb hjelpefiler installasjons-program" />

    <Media Id="1" Cabinet="media1.cab" EmbedCab="yes" />

    <Binary Id="BarCodeDriver" SourceFile="barcode_install.exe" />
    <CustomAction Id="InstallBarCodeDriver" BinaryKey="BarCodeDriver" ExeCommand="" Execute="deferred" Return="check" HideTarget="no" Impersonate="no" />

    <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
      <Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder">
        <Directory Id="INSTALLLOCATION" Name="FDVweb">
          <!-- TODO: Remove the comments around this Component element and the ComponentRef below in order to add resources to this installer. -->
          <!-- <Component Id="ProductComponent" Guid="55a9465e-2350-48bc-9786-22a036ea7304"> -->
            <!-- TODO: Insert files, registry keys, and other resources here. -->
          <!-- </Component> -->
        </Directory>
      </Directory>

    </Directory>

    <DirectoryRef Id="FontsFolder">
      <Component Id="C128_100" Guid="72E7E1D2-DEE7-4E0B-939F-5460AD432BEF">
        <File Id="C128_100.tff" Source="fonts\C128_100.tff" TrueType="yes" />
      </Component>
      <Component Id="C128_200" Guid="230EE8B3-06F9-4D88-AFF5-3D26AF0741AD">
        <File Id="C128_200.tff" Source="fonts\C128_200.tff" TrueType="yes" />
      </Component>
      <Component Id="C128_300" Guid="3DC98EE5-B969-453E-B4E9-5D5BC1416F24">
        <File Id="C128_300.tff" Source="fonts\C128_300.tff" TrueType="yes" />
      </Component>
      <Component Id="C128_400" Guid="8CFCAFBE-C7B8-46F1-9C6D-ACF2D881BAEE">
        <File Id="C128_400.tff" Source="fonts\C128_400.tff" TrueType="yes" />
      </Component>
    </DirectoryRef>

    <Feature Id="Complete" Title="FDVwebInstall" Level="1">
      <!-- TODO: Remove the comments around this ComponentRef element and the Component above in order to add resources to this installer. -->
      <!-- <ComponentRef Id="ProductComponent" /> -->
      <ComponentRef Id="C128_100" />
      <ComponentRef Id="C128_200" />
      <ComponentRef Id="C128_300" />
      <ComponentRef Id="C128_400" />

      <!-- Note: The following ComponentGroupRef is required to pull in generated authoring from project references. -->
      <ComponentGroupRef Id="Product.Generated" />
    </Feature>
  </Product>
</Wix>
```

I don't need a definite answer, a link to resources explaining how to achieve what I want would go a long way.

Comment: So which bit(s) are/are not working from your list of 4? Also, what if this "pre-defined" location does not and *can not* exist?

Comment: It **can** always exist, cause if it doesn't the system isn't compatible, however, the distribution of this installer is not large enough to be concerned with that (inhouse use only, controled environments). If the folder does not exist, it should be created. The part I'm not understanding (at all) is how to reference that absolute path, and weather it should be nested below the SourceDir or not, and how to setup the order of execution (the only thing that matters is that the external binary is run last).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution to my problem.
The answer was to use the Directory `WINDOWSVOLUME`.

Here is the solution in WIX-xml:

```
    <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
      <Directory Id="WINDOWSVOLUME">
        <Directory Id="DvWebImp" Name="dvimport">
          <Component Id="DataReadApp" Guid="YOURGUID-4423-9C81-29937C31DF8A">
            <File Id="Data_Read.exe" Source="Data_Read.exe" />
            <File Id="Data_Read.ini" Source="Data_Read.ini" />
          </Component>
        </Directory>
      </Directory>
    </Directory>
```